# Does /var keep growing in size?

Tags: logs, disk-usage, logrotate, var

[tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/var.html) quotes /var as:

> Files in /var/log can often grow indefinitely, and may require
>   cleaning at regular intervals.

So without cleaning, using a system for a long enough period will fill up all of /var.

Do some distros rotate logs automatically or is in generally accepted it's the user's role. With so many new people getting into *nix, this be better know, and how should this be handled?

Comment: To add, I asked this while setting up a CentOS VM with a small disk, with intent on putting /var in it's own partition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `logrotate` which cleans /var/log regularly by using cron jobs.

It is normally installed automatically (at least in Debian and its derivatives  like Ubuntu).

Comment: Good to know this is done by default, very sane. I found /etc/cron.daily/logrotate which led to /etc/logrotate.conf, it keeps 4 weeks of logs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to put a cron job for rotating the log. depending on your logs you can have cronjob which moves the `/var/log` to `/var/log.<timestamp>`once in 30 days or 2 months or If you want to delete it. remove it using a `cron job`. for putting cron job see [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)